# PostgreSQL right join with group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

My problem seems to be have an easy solution but I can't get to it.
I have an select joining two tables: `users` and `login_log`. I need to show each user and how many logins he has (including the ones that have not performed any login yet) so I do a `right join` on users table.

Here is my select:

```
select users.id,count(*)
from login_log
right join users on login_log.user_id=users.id 
group by users.id
```

The problem is that for users that have no entry in login_log table the select show the value of the `count(*)` as 1, but it suposed to be 0 (or null);

The result is next:

```
user_id | count
----------------
   73      4
   59      2
   47      1
    3      1
   61      1
   67      1 (suppose to be 0)
   14      1 (suppose to be 0)
   46      1 (suppose to be 0)
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to count something that's optional (ie something in the table that may or may not have entries), not the entire row. For example;

```
select users.id,count(login_log.user_id)
from login_log
right join users on login_log.user_id=users.id 
group by users.id
```

The reason for this is that the query gives at least one row per user, so a `COUNT(*)` - which counts rows - will always return at least 1.